# Equidistant Anchor Links on Same Line for Squarespace

Tags: css, hyperlink, menu, squarespace

I've been scouring the internet and Squarespace forum for answers to this problem, but so far can't find any luck! I understand basic code and CSS but can't seem to figure this one out myself :(

I'm trying to make a line of anchor links on an Index with equidistant text links on a line. When I view what I have now via Tablet or Phone view, they get broken up in a janky way.

Is there a way either: restrict this so they stay on one line or adjust in a way so they neatly stack on top on one another?

I'm trying to recreate something to the "Community Workspace Progamming" link effect here (https://www.the-wing.com/why-the-wing/)

The images of what's going on with my site in Tablet view are attached.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Z72.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for simply stacking them on top when the screen becomes smaller (like in a phone or tablet, then this will do:

```css
.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 760px) {
  .menu li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <li><h2>LOCATIONS</h2></li>
  <li><h2>EVENTS</h2></li>
  <li><h2>PERSONAL STYLING</h2></li>
</div>
```

It changes according to screen size, so it's all in a line in screens bigger than 760px, and it becomes stacked in smaller screens. You can change that size at the @media to suit your needs.

However, the site you've linked is using what's called a burger menu. Here's a good implementation that I [found online](https://codepen.io/jlnljn/pen/LkXoBb), but it's a bit more complicated to implement.

I don't know anything about Squarespace, but if I were you, I would look for my template's Burger Menu in the template's documentation. I hope this helps!